# Powerline password conversion

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design

I read [this](https://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/security/282-infiltrating-a-network-via-powerline-homeplugav-adapters) post from Ben Tasker describing how to take control of a powerline network. Since I am interested in security, I tried to do the same thing, to see if it was possible. I used Devolo devices, since those are the only ones I have.

I followed the described steps, and failed in "generating the password from MAC". The password generated by [openplc](https://github.com/qca/open-plc-utils) using the `mac2pw` program is incorrect (I checked by comparing the generated password with the one printed on the device).

I have two openplc versions, one from June 2014, and the latest. The latest includes some random parts and prints in an odd format, dunno why, specially because the base algorithm is the same. The oldest prints the password in the expected format.

Following Ben's reasoning, it is most likely that Devolo used a different algorithm for MAC -> password conversion. How could we discover what algorithm is used by Devolo? I have no experience in cracking algorithms, but I would start with:

- Changing the order of the operations
- Changing any constants to a large range of values

If these don't work, we could assume that Devolo used some other algorithm not based on the one present in openplc. If that is so, how could we discover such algorithm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "how could we discover such algorithm?" Reverse engineering the firmware. Changing the order of operations or constants is more or less brute force, which could take years to complete.

Comment: I have no firmware to reverse engineer, since I have no software/firmware/binary that implements the Devolo algorithm.

Comment: unless they did something very stupid, you'll never figure it out with blackbox testing (i.e., give it an input, see what the output it). I suggest you head over to [ReverseEngineering.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) to see if they can help you extract the firmware and reverse engineer it.

Comment: The firmware of these devices does not make such conversion, so there is nothing to reverse engineer. I was lookinhy for some way to adapt the existing open source code and try to obtain the same algorithm as Devolo.

Comment: If the firmware doesn't make the conversion, what does? Something has to, right? Reverse engineer that. My point is, if all you can do is black box testing to try to figure out how it works, you'll likely never  succeed.

Comment: Something has to, of course. But that algorithm is not present in the firmware of the adaptors, it's proprietary of Devolo. The adaptors do not need to make such conversion. What I am trying to discover is how to make small changes to the base algorithm in order to emulate Devolo's algorithm. Of course it could be close to impossible, but where to start?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it's more about reverse engineering than about cryptography. I'm not migrating it to reverse engineering because it's a "How do I get started reversing this firmware?" question and thus rather broad.

Comment: The global objective is to break/modify/uncover Devolo's algorithm... I just don't know where to begin, hence coming here for tips.